# Unable to click on the selenium text alert

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, visual-studio-code, webdriver

I'm trying to click on the text alert in selenium but when I use the click function it doesn't recognize the command.

My code is as follows:

```py
chrome.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[14]/td[1]/input[1]').click()

sleep(3)

alert = WebDriverWait(s.chrome, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),"Confirma a 
operação?")

alert.accept

print("alert accepted")
```

This is the page element I'm trying to click:

```js
input type="SUBMIT" name="BTN_ENTER" value="Confirmar" class="Button" gxevent="EENTER." onclick="if( confirm( 'Confirma a operação?')) {GX_setgridevent( 45,  12);GX_setevent('EENTER.');} else return false;" gxctx="_" onfocus="gxonfocus2(this, 59,'',45)" gxoldvalue="Confirmar"
```

I saw that there after I configure it, it has an option called `one click` but I don't know what value I have to set for it to recognize the element.

Answer (score 1):

When you check the internal implementation of `alert_is_present()` internally handle the `switch_to.alert` so we can handle the alert

```
chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='BTN_ENTER']").click()

WebDriverWait(chrome, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),'Confirma a operação?').accept()
print("alert accepted")
```

**Update**

As per the `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` you can handle it as below

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.set_capability('unhandledPromptBehavior', 'accept')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: I tested this code and the following error appears:

   self.error_handler.check_response(response)
   File "C:\Users\Luis.Serpa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 241, in check_response
     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: Confirm operation?
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Confirm operation?}
   (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)

Comment: Ok so it is showing UnexpectedAlertPresentException

Comment: I can click on confirm but when I click on confirm it issues the text alert but it doesn't do OK for it to download the report.

Comment: Ok so the Alert is the expected behaviour of the application ? can you check I have updated my answer

Comment: Got it, I removed:
  chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='BTN_ENTER']").click()

and he did the direct confirmation, thank you very much